# How much force in LBs could a 10in long 3in wide 0.5in thick piece of neodymium magnet repel off a 0.5in thick sheet of neodymium magnet

Tags: magnets

I know nothing about magnets and have an idea that I don’t know is possible to carry out. I want to replace the soles of a pair of shoes with one whole custom neodymium magnet on each shoe. What size do the magnets need to be and what size would the sheet of magnet below it need to be in order to repel at least 135 lbs like 1 inch off the ground? I’m not interested in balancing or anything like that just need to know if these magnets could even repel that much force. The size in the title is based on the sole of a shoe I measured so a follow up question would be would that size work and again what size sheet of magnet below it would I also need at a minimum? I hope this makes some sense thank you! I also have thought about electromagnets but that’s far too complicated for me!

Comment: This is a lot more complicated than you think. Magnets may be poled different ways. I’d guess based on the information you have provided the question is not solvable.

Comment: I figured there was a lot of info I’m missing or not understanding. Is there any other information I can try to provide to help solve it? Or is this something that has to be experimented to find out? Thank you!

Comment: I’m not a magnet expert. It might be analyzed by finite element analysis, but you would need an expert. Just trying things experimentally is unlikely to produce an optimal solution.